# didSelectRowAt passing data to new view

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to pass my object to a new view and am having trouble passing the data. It keeps returning nil. I have tried to do this using protocols and delegates and it also kept returning nil. I decided to just pass the data in didSelectRowAt however when the new view is loaded it is not displaying the correct information. It is returning nil.I tried to test it by simply passing the name only. I am not sure what exactly I am doing wrong here. Both currentUser and name return nil

```swift
class HomeVC: {
    var sortedArr = [Response.Users]()

    func showDetail() {
        let modalViewController = DetailView()
        modalViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        present(modalViewController, animated: true) {
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! UserTableCell
        let arr = sortedArr[indexPath.row]
        cell.titleLabel.text = arr.fullName
        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let arr = sortedArr[indexPath.row]

        let detailVC = DetailView()
        detailVC.currentUser = [arr]
        detailVC.name = arr.fullName
        showDetail()
    }
}
class DetailView: UIViewController {

    var currentUser: [Response.Users]!
    var name: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        print(name)
        print(currentUser)
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Comment: have you got the value  sortedArr[indexPath.row] in didSelectRowAt

Comment: ad the code of cellforRowAtIndex as well

Comment: yes I get the value in didSelectRowAt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are created a object inside didSelectRowAt and then call the method `showDetail()` in which you are going to create a new instance of same method and then push last one in which you are not set any value related to 
currentUser and name then how you can get the values

Change didSelectRowAt methods

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let arr = sortedArr[indexPath.row]

    let detailVC = DetailView()
    detailVC.currentUser = [arr]
    detailVC.name = arr.fullName
    detailVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    present(detailVC, animated: true) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to pass detailVC object from didSelect method to function showDetail()'s parameter.

Please try this,

```
class HomeVC: {
    var sortedArr = [Response.Users]()

    func showDetail(detailVC: DetailView) {
        detailVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        present(detailVC, animated: true) {
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! UserTableCell
        let arr = sortedArr[indexPath.row]
        cell.titleLabel.text = arr.fullName
        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let arr = sortedArr[indexPath.row]

        let detailVC = DetailView()
        detailVC.currentUser = [arr]
        detailVC.name = arr.fullName
        showDetail(detailVC: detailVC)
    }
}
class DetailView: UIViewController {

    var currentUser: [Response.Users]!
    var name: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        print(name)
        print(currentUser)
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you both answers solved my issue, I am not sure which one is a better approach or if its just preference.

Comment: Both are the right answers, you can use whatever you want to use. Enjoy and share...